# How do I use the ko.mapping plugin to refresh a part of my view model?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a complex view model like this:

```
    function DiaryBundleViewModel() {
        var self = this;

        self.existingJobSearchViewModel = new ExistingJobSearchViewModel(self);

        self.DiaryBundle = ko.observable();
        self.Appointment = ko.observable();
...
```

I have bound my view model to my UI as in:

```
var vm = new DiaryBundleViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

In my view model, I have a function to fetch an Appointment from the server.

When I get my result back from the server, I do this:

```
self.Appointment(result);
```

and the UI updates with the fields showing the appointment.

However, only the Appointment itself is a ko.observable. There are inter-related properties on my Appointment object that I want to fire changes in the UI. So, I need the ko.mapping plugin.

However, I'm stuggling with how to use it in this instance.

If I do this:

```
self.Appointment = ko.mapping.fromJS(result);
```

it doesn't work, as the UI is already bound to self.Appointment and I've just overwritten that so it won't see the change.

So, I tried:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(result, self.Appointment);
```

but that doesn't work either.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

First you need to create an AppointmentVm and there use the Mapping plugin.

Appointment:

```
 var AppointmentVm= function(data) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, { }, this);
};
```

and in you main viewmodel you use:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {
        'Appointments': {
            create: function(options) {
                return new AppointmentVm(options.data);
            }
        }
    },this);
```

This map the children object.

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't quite work for me. I'll detail what I did to make this work in my own answer.

Comment: Hi Craig, I think your answer to this will solve my issue, any update on your answer?